# Is there an HTML 5 way of submitting fields with the same name but different identifiers?

Tags: html, forms

I would like to submit multiple ROWS of field columns using an HTML form with the only difference being the corresponding server side identifier.

Pseudo:

```
    ID(257) -> Name, Color, Price
    ID(415) -> Name, Color, Price
```

I prefer NOT to:

1. Have each group as its own form and submit via JavaScript.
2. Concatenate the id and real name and unmerge on the server.

Thanks

Comment: All forms-values are serialized into something then sent to the server.  Typically this is form-urlencoded, but you could use js to encode it as json or something else.  Whether or not you have to manually 'unmerge' on the server depends a lot on how you choose to encode the data and what your server/language/framework looks like

Comment: This has less to do with HTML than with your server architecture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the same input name when attaching a [] to it, in PHP this will result in an array on submission:

```
<?php
print_r($_POST);
?>

<form method="post">
<input type="text" name="name[257]">
<input type="text" name="name[415]">
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

Result:

```
Array
(
    [name] => Array
        (
            [257] => first field
            [415] => second field
        )

)
```

Comment: PHP creates an array out of this, other languages might not do that.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, OP didn't specify what he's using.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using PHP as your server side language this is easy. Just name your fields with brackets which is array syntax in PHP:

Pseudo code:

```
name[1] = 'Name, Color, Price'
name[2] = 'Name, Color, Price'
```